# Как заставить код ждать при нажатии ENTER python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, у меня есть цикл:

```
while True:
 print("Cycle")
```

Мне надо, чтобы при нажатии ENTER цикл временно остановился (с написанием некоторого текста) до повторного нажатия ENTER.
Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался с этим. Лучше использовать библиотеку `keyboard` и цикл.

```
import keyboard

key = 'alt'

while True:
    print("Цикл")
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
        input("Цикл приостановлен. Нажмите ENTER чтобы продолжить")
```

Таким образом, при нажатии на **ALT** цикл приостанавливается.

Answer (score -1):

```
on_run = True 
while True:
    while on_run:
        print("Cycle")
```

Переключайте переменную on_run когда вам будет нужно, при этом программа будет работать, а цикл нет.

Comment: Хорошо. Как отслеживать нажатие ENTER в данном примере?

Comment: Есть, библиотека keyboard.
https://qna.habr.com/q/634385