# Как считать нажатие клавиши в Python программе?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть вот такой код

```
if(selected == 0):
    print(tabss[1]+'[x] Start game')
    print(tabss[1]+'[ ] Continue game')
    print(tabss[1]+'[ ] Exit game')
elif(selected == 1):
    print(tabss[1]+'[ ] Start game')
    print(tabss[1]+'[x] Continue game')
    print(tabss[1]+'[ ] Exit game')
elif(selected == 2):
    print(tabss[1]+'[ ] Start game')
    print(tabss[1]+'[ ] Continue game')
    print(tabss[1]+'[x] Exit game')
input()
```

Мне нужна ***замена input()***, чтобы при нажатии клавиш W и S изменялось значение selected. Я знаю, как изменить значение переменной, но не знаю как считать нажатие на клавишу. Можете ли вы  подсказать, как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать модуль keyboard (установка - pip3 install keyboard), а в условии нажатия использовать  `if keyboard.is_pressed('ваша клавиша'):`

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как сделать, чтобы программа ждала, пока я нажму на клавишу. Код, что я показал, находится в цикле, и мне нужно, чтоб программа ожидала нажатия клавиши. Заранее спасибо

Comment: @justfollowyourdreams тот же цикл, что и в ответе, если я вас правильно понял

Comment: Нет, в ответе это выбор, а ещё выше всего этого цикл. Мне нужно, чтобы программа приостановилась, пока пользователь не нажмёт на кнопку. Условно говоря, мне нужна функция, которая будет ждать, пока пользователь нажмёт на кнопку

Comment: @justfollowyourdreams https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295029/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-enter-python вот аналогичный вопрос